# How to update datatype of column in a dataview

Tags: xml, xsd, boolean, xmldatasource

i have a below function in which the variable dataCollection hold the dataview having some  datas. i need to change the column "AllDay" in the dataCollection from string datatype to boolean data type.

```
public override void FetchData(IEnumerable data)
        {
                foreach (DataRowView ds in data)
                {
                    if ((ds.Row["AllDay"].Equals("false")))
                        ds.Row["AllDay"] = false;
                    else if ((ds.Row["AllDay"].Equals("true")))
                        ds.Row["AllDay"] = true;
                }
        }
```

But it does not works.please help me resolve this.
thanks in advance...

Comment: I think we need to see the code that generates `data` to be able to answer

Comment: data is from asp:xmldatasource..... i get those data from XML file

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible. `XmlDataSource` does not have a mechanism to declare the type of specific attributes or elements in the XML, hence everything will be a string .